# compare operators

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, validation

How do I Create a webpage using JavaScript that takes a number from the user and compares it against three ranges of numbers, unsing 3 functions, `checklow()`, `checkmedium()` and `checkhigh()`?

Comment: Have you at least had a go at doing this yourself? We're not a homework service!

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<form onsubmit="myValidation()">
    <input type="text" id="t1" name="t1" />
    <input type="text" id="t2" name="t2" />
    <input type="text" id="t3" name="t3" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

javascript:

```
    function myValidation()
    {
        for (var i=0; i < 3 ; i ++)
        {
            var t = document.getElementById('t'+(i+1)).value;
            if checklow(t)
                alert('low');
            if checkmedium(t)
                alert('medium');
            if checkhigh(t)
                alert('high');
        }
    }
```

now you have to write your 3 functions...